# Perl date validation and updating an SQL database

Tags: sql, perl

`$curdate` is in the format `yyyymmdd`

For example `20141225`

If ($curdate) = 'dd' part.  Of 25 then

Update table account set seq value in account = 20150101

How do I proceed in Perl?

As I'm completely new to Perl. Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Please explain yourself better. It sounds like you want to set a database field to `20150101` if the days field of `$curdate` is 25, but that makes little sense

Comment: @Borodin-you are right..How to validate the 'dd' part ..its little bit confusing me.Im completely stuck on this condition part..your help is appreciated..thanks in advance

Comment: I've had to vote to close this question. *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question* If you can explain yourself better then please do so: your question is far too short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify the requirements.
From what you describe, my analysis of your problem is.

- You want to look at the day component of the string
- Based on the day component of the string, you will update the table

So in semi code and pseudocode

```
my $curdate = 20140125;
my $day_component = substr($curdate, 6, 2);

if ($day_component == '25') {
    # Run SQL to update table
}
```